# Scaling figure to two columns

Tags: floats, multicol, wide-image

I'm writing a two-column document using the multicols environment. Is there a possibility to position an image exactly at the head of some page spanning over both columns? Here's an illustration of what I'd like to do.

Page One:

```
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
```

Page Two:

```
*************
*   IMAGE   *
*************
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
```

Page Three:

```
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
aaaaaa|aaaaaa
```

I know that i could terminate the multicolumn environment, include the picture, and then reactivate it. - But that's not what I want to do because this will cause the image to appear somewhere in the middle of the page (I'd like it to be at the top of the page where the figure is mentioned).

Comment: At the top of the text area or in the header, if you have one? In the first case, did you try with the `figure*` environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could wrap your image in `figure*` floating environment. The asterix simply spans the image across 2 columns. You could also specify the `!t` placement holder to instruct Latex to keep the image on top.

Comment: Thanks, since I never use the figure environment I didn't know that it could do that! Very nice solution, thank you!